# Change zsh auto titles to hide user and host

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Right now, when I open a zsh termite terminal the window title is

`user@host: ~`

Is there any way to remove the `user@host` part without entirely disabling auto titles?

If I enable `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE` in my `.zshrc` then the window title is always `termite`. I want to just change the window title when I'm browsing directories so that it doesn't show the user and host - only the directory, but if, for example, I open `nmtui` I want the window title to automatically become `nmtui` instead of staying as `termite`.

Answer (score 11):

Dug around a bit more and figured it out!

In my zsh theme (oh-my-via), I added this:

`ZSH_THEME_TERM_TITLE_IDLE="%~"`

which overrides the default value found [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/3705d47bb3f3229234cba992320eadc97a221caf/lib/termsupport.zsh) (`ZSH_THEME_TERM_TITLE_IDLE="%n@%m: %~"`)

Comment: For those who'd like to configure it some more, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13660697/6094756